# Perl - Getting an error with Net/SSLeay.pm - I am trying to POST XML via HTTPS web service

Tags: perl, web-services, https

I am trying to use Net/SSLeay.pm in Perl, code says use Net::SSLeay

Error message says the following -

Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at test.pl line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 7.

I installed SSLeay.pm via Perl Package Manager and verified it - 
Crypt-SSLeay
OpenSSL support for LWP
    Version:    0.57
    Released:   2008-05-02
    Author: David Landgren 
    CPAN:   http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-SSLeay-0.57/

Installed files:
    C:/Perl/lib/Crypt/SSLeay.pm
    C:/Perl/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/CTX.pm
    C:/Perl/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/Conn.pm
    C:/Perl/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/Err.pm
    C:/Perl/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/MainContext.pm
    C:/Perl/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/X509.pm
    C:/Perl/lib/Net/SSL.pm
    C:/Perl/lib/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/.packlist
    C:/Perl/lib/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.bs
    C:/Perl/lib/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.dll
    C:/Perl/lib/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.exp
    C:/Perl/lib/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.lib

I am unsure as to why my script does not find it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[Crypt-SSLeay](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-SSLeay/) and [Net-SSLeay](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SSLeay/) are two different CPAN distributions. If you want to use Net::SSLeay, install "Net-SSLeay" ppm distribution.